# Looking for title of search & find book with woodland creatures

Tags: story-identification

I am trying desperately to find a book that I read as a child.
It was a search and find  sort of book (along the lines of Where's Waldo) filled with woodland creatures. The pictures would show their lives above and below ground, and they were possibly fighting a war. The pictures were done in the style of Redwall by Brian Jacques, except this book was without words.

It would be awesome if you could help my identify this book! Thanks!

Comment: Were they personified (e.g. wearing clothes, using tools, etc)?

Comment: @Richard yes they were!! do you happen to know the title of the book??? That would be amazing!!

Comment: Alas, no. I was merely trying to ascertain whether this question was on topic for the site.